# How to inject custom headers in a response attribute before sending it to client application?

Tags: mule, mule-esb

Suppose I have a mule application in which I consumed Rest API and got a response from it.After that I have to inject some extra headers and then send the response back to the listener.How can I implement this?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are trying to achieve. You can set up the headers in the Response section.

[image]